# Simple Task Manager like Windows Fewer Details Mode

Tags: process, system-monitor

I am looking for an application that is similar to Windows Task Manager but in its Fewer Details mode. This really isn't for me per se but for school. I take proctored tests for school which only officially supports windows or mac, but they use Zoom for the remote connections and this is something that will run on linux. I can't find any logical reason for the school NOT to support linux, especially considering I am in their Software Development track. The test proctors always wish to see the Windows Task Manager and will require me to put it in Fewer Details view to confirm only the Zoom client and my web browser are open. If I can get something that looks like this on linux, I highly doubt they would say anything about it at all. I know its a long shot but I figured I would at least ask after my searches have come up empty. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you are looking for  `gnome system monitor`  or `lxtask` or `xfce4-taskmanager`...

Comment: Not quite that, something even more simple. The Fewer Details view of Task Manager literally shows ONLY applications that have open windows. That's all the school cares to see.